# How to create temporary record in MYSQL which will get deleted after 30 minutes or closing of browser?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a web application that would requires me to reserve a seat for the customer for 30 minutes or closing of the browser before the reservation gets deleted. Any suggestion of the best way to do this?

I thought of adding a record into MYSQL and runs a cron job but that would not give the users the most updated results. Any advises?

Thanks!

Comment: Really your last question gets closed and you create the same question and expect a different outcome? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705126/how-to-temporary-reserve-a-seat-in-mysql-for-30-minutes

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have whatever page that displays current reservations check the table to make sure it's created within the last 30 minutes? Beyond that, I don't know what you're trying to do w/r/t the browser closing and what not but I'm sure there are better ways to go about that as well. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am developing an application whereby users will reserve a 'seat' in the event that they are registering for when they are at the registration page. Which means that they already have 'reserve' a seat before they actually pay. However, the system will always clean up orders that had not paid 30 minutes from the time they 'reserve' a seat.

Answer (score 5):

Write a record with an expiration date. Use that expiration date when writing queries. Clean up expired records every so often.

Closing the browser however is more complicated and not reliable. Connections to the server in http are stateless and as such you really wont know when the browser has been closed. You can regularly poll with ajax and delete records when there are no longer any poll updates.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is actually 2 problems:

- How do you clean up old records

and

- How do you *ignore* expired records.

Add an `expire_time` field to your reservations table. You probably have some logic that looks at how many seats are still available, add the `expire_time` to that logic so that expired records are ignored.

Then write a script or function that gets called periodically (cron works, so does `register_shutdown_handler()`) to clean up the expired records.

This way, should your cron ever fail or be slow for some reason, you're not accidentally blocking new reservations. You could even skip the cleanup step completely and take the (minor) performance hit.

Comment: That cron could run even only once per day - if You have `expiration_date` column You could select all the records (seats) that are not reserved - and an expired and not confirmed reservation means that the seat is not reserved...

Comment: I am thinking of using cron job as well. My solution is to add have two fields 'created' and 'status' on the table. So if the record is older than 30 minutes cron job will periodically update and clean those reservation that are not paid. But then again, how often should the cron job run to minimize cases which reservations had expired by the cron job have not update them?

Comment: This is why you want to add the `expire_date` to the table so you always know which records you can ignore, even if the cron runs a little late. With this approach it doesn't actually matter whether the cron runs at all. You might get a slight performance hit if you have many expired records. You should weigh this off against the cost of implementing a cleanup script.

Comment: As I said - cron could run even once per day. In Your queries to obtain the free seats, check for `status` *not-paid* and `created` is older than 30 minutes or no record at all, to obtain the reserved seats check for `created` is not older than 30 minutes and `status` is *not-paid` and to obtain the reserved seats check for `status` is *paid*... Cron could run at 04:00 hours and delete all the rows that have `created` older than 30 minutes and `status` is *not-paid*...

Answer (score -1):

I believe it should be resolved by session, not the mysql.

But if you insist, you should update item every time page get hits, and you can do also some sweepups

**EDIT**
Yes, of course. The reservation system must be multi user. If one user does the reservation than the other user must not be able to get the seat.

Yes, simple resolution is just to add there new column called reserved that will specify the time until it is reserved.

Why do you need cron for it?

BTW: sessions are stored on server not client. cookies are stored in client not server.

Comment: Session is not enough - at the very same time another user with another session could place a reservation for the very same seat... How would You handle that?

Comment: I had thought of session but it will not be accurate because sessions is stored locally and not on the server. There will be a case whereby the seats are actually unavailable but different sessions on user end receive the latest results.